# Is it possible to set the specific section which is non-optimazed code in C code when I compile ARM-series code in IAR Embedded workbench

Tags: c, optimization, iar

I use IAR Embedded workbench to edit C code and compile. 
I am very curious if I set Optimizations level at High in IAR project options, why the sequence of programming in code was changed.

I have check the reason for change. it may be related with branch speculation.

I'd like to know if I want to use Optimizations level at High, Can I set the specific code section which is not sequential changed by using special tags or options.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently I don't use IAR. So I cannot test the specific preprocessor directive.
But the following should work for functions with IAR, according to the official [development guide](http://supp.iar.com/filespublic/updinfo/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf).

```
#pragma optimize=none
void foo(void)
{
    /* Do something, but don't optimize this function */ 
}
```

> **Description**
>   Use this pragma directive to decrease the optimization level, or to
>   turn off some specific optimizations. This pragma directive only
>   affects the function that follows immediately after the directive.

*Quote from the development guide (Page 253).*